# php anchor tag with image in between

Tags: php

hello i keep getting an error message when i try to place a image file inbetween 2 anchor tags. i am using echo for the obvous reason i am using php but i get this message when i try to refresh the page:

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in E:\Game Downloads\Applications\Xampp\htdocs\WEBSITE DESIGN(PHP)\signed_in.php on line 189*

**below is what i have got so far but ive been messing around with the way the speech marks are used and the quotation marks**

```
echo"<div class='add_to_cart'>";
   echo"<a href='#'>""<img src='Images/ADD-TO-CART-copy-4.png' />" "</a>";
echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple as below -

```
echo  '<a href="#"><img src="Images/ADD-TO-CART-copy-4.png" /></a>';
```

Comment: thanks sorry for the simple question, as you can tell im very new to php and just started learning it. thanks for the reply ill give this to correct answer once 12 mins is past

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<div class='add_to_cart'><a href='#'><img src='Images/ADD-TO-CART-copy-4.png' /></a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print '<div class="add_to_cart">';
print '<a href="#"><img src="Images/ADD-TO-CART-copy-4.png" /></a>';
print '</div>;
```

or similarily:

```
print '<div class="add_to_cart"><a href="#"><img src="Images/ADD-TO-CART-copy-4.png" /></a></div>';
```